# is it safe to use static inteface in application class?

Tags: java, android, interface, static

Is there a problem with using these classes?
Does this static interface make the application class any problem later?

```
public class App extends Application {
private static KareezAPI apiService;
private InternetConnectionListener mInternetConnectionListener;
public static final int DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
public void setInternetConnectionListener(InternetConnectionListener listener) {
    mInternetConnectionListener = listener;
}

public void removeInternetConnectionListener() {
    mInternetConnectionListener = null;
}

public KareezAPI getApiService(Activity activity) {
    if (apiService == null) {
        apiService = provideRetrofit(KareezAPI.BASE_URL,activity).create(KareezAPI.class);
        }
    return apiService;
}
                                   }
```

this is the interface:

```
public interface KareezAPI{
String BASE_URL="https://baseurl.heroapp.com/";
@POST("register")
Call<RegisterResponse> RegisterUser( @Body RegisterData registerData);

@POST("login")
Call<RegisterResponse> LoginUser(@Body LoginData loginData); public interface LoginUserCallback{
    public void onResponse(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Response<RegisterResponse> response);
    public void onFailure(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Throwable t);
}


}
```

and this is the using of this interface and app class

```
((App) activity.getApplication()).getApiService(activity).LoginUser(loginData).enqueue(new 
                                               Callback<RegisterResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<RegisterResponse> call, @NonNull 
             Response<RegisterResponse> response) {
            loginUserCallback.onResponse(call, response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<RegisterResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            loginUserCallback.onFailure(call, t);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it makes no sense to add Api logic to Application class. What you can do is to use Retrofit in your `KareezAPI` interface, and write something like:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

KareezAPI service = retrofit.create(KareezAPI.class);
```

Then, when you want to use it, write

```
KareezAPI.service.LoginUser().enqueue()...
```

where ever you like.